# DBSCAN for outlier detection

Tags: cluster-analysis, detection

I want to use DBSCAN for outlier detection. Can it be used for that? Also is it possible for the algorithm to give some outlier score as given by LOF.

I have gone through basics concepts of DBSCAN but I am unable to find a way to generate an score for outliers such as in LOF